# Using a 24 Hour Window for Amazon Kinesis Analytics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I have a Streaming Data use case where for every record inserted into a Kinesis Stream, I would like to calculate a value based on the last 24 hours worth of records.

Now, Kinesis Analytics seems to fit this bill nicely. I can use a `WINDOW` with a `RANGE INTERVAL '1' DAY PRECEDING` to get my aggregation. My Kinesis Stream is set to persist records for 26 hours.

My conflict comes from the [Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/best-practices.html#bp-authoring-sqlcode) documentation.

Specifically:

> In your SQL statement, we recommend that you do not specify time-based window that is longer than one hour for the following reasons:
>
> - If an application needs to be restarted, either because you updated the application or for Amazon Kinesis Data Analytics internal reasons, all data included in the window must be read again from the streaming data source. This will take time before Amazon Kinesis Data Analytics can emit output for that window.
> - Amazon Kinesis Data Analytics must maintain everything related to the application's state, including relevant data, for the duration. This will consume significant Amazon Kinesis Data Analytics processing units.

I want to be sure I understand the consequences of this.

Say I proceed with my plans and implement this using Kinesis Analytics. Then for whatever reason my Kinesis Analytics Application has to be restarted. For context, my application deals with approximately 1 million records a day and each record is approximately 550 bytes.

If my Kinesis Analytics Application restarts, what will be I be dealing with since I would be ignoring this recommendation:

> we recommend that you do not specify time-based window that is longer than one hour

I have also considered skipping Kinesis Analytics and just feeding my rows into RDS (postgres - Single Deployment) and triggering a lambda to run my calculations or doing something with Redis (still exploring those consequences).

Comment: Is the query something that could be split into multiple smaller windows that ran each hour and produced a result that could be combined with previous results to give an aggregate result which is still correct?

Comment: No, it's a query that for every event received, it needs to run a new 24 aggregate for that event's moment in time. AKA query/sum `new event time`  - `24h`

Comment: Understood.  In that case I suspect it would be better to do as you suggest, and pipe events into a database (Postgres as you mention, or if you had huge amounts of data that you sometimes wanted to do analytics with more than just a 24 hour window, RedShift).